# Remove punctuations from NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

How to remove punctuations like "," from an NSMutableArray?

Comment: What your array contains? Do you need to remove "," if is is an element of array or remove all "," from all strings in array?

Comment: Paste some code and tell us what you want to do and be more specific. We can not guess your problems!

Comment: I have a NSMUtableArray which has a set of numbers.they are separated by commas  (
    006d,
    0081,
    006d,
    007f,
    0072,
    007a,
    007f,
    0073,
    008e,
    006f,
    00a1,
    006e,
    00b4,
    006e,
    00c2,
    006e,
    00ca, this is my output want to remove commas

Comment: Just to be sure: Each element in the array is a string containing several values separated by commas?

Comment: I am using nslog to print the array.The array is taking some points my code is [myarray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%04x",(NSInteger)lastPoint.x ]]; [myarray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%04x",(NSInteger)lastPoint.y ]];NSLog(@"%@",myarray);

Answer (score 3):

There are no commas in your array or your array elements. When you use `NSLog()` to log an array, it uses the NeXTSTEP format, which states that parentheses are used to delimit the array and commas are used to delimit elements.

So if

```
NSLog(@"%@", myarray);
```

outputs

```
( 006d, 0081, 006d, 007f )
```

this means that the array contains @"006d" in the first position, @"0081" in the second position, "006d" in the third position, and @"007f" in the fourth position.

The commas (and the parentheses) are only part of the representation of the array for output; they’re not part of the array/array elements per se.

Instead of using `NSLog()`, you could use the following code snippet to output your array:

```
NSLog(@"beginning of array");
for (id element in myarray) NSLog(@"%@", element);
NSLog(@"end of array");
```

which will output something like:

```
beginning of array
006d
0081
006d
007f
end of array
```

---

**Edit based on comment:** It looks like you want to join the elements of the array. Try this:

```
NSString *allElements = [myarray componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

`-[NSArray componentsJoinedByString:]`, as the method name says, joins all the elements in the array, separating them by a string. If you use `@""` as the separating string, the elements will be joined one right after another.

If you want to output that string:

```
NSLog(@"%@", allElements);
```

Comment: It worked but printing like 2011-05-26 09:39:33.052 Switch[24344:40b] beginning of array
2011-05-26 09:39:33.053 Switch[24344:40b] 0067
2011-05-26 09:39:33.053 Switch[24344:40b] 00a1
2011-05-26 09:39:33.054 Switch[24344:40b] 0069
2011-05-26 09:39:33.054 Switch[24344:40b] 009f
2011-05-26 09:39:33.054 Switch[24344:40b] 006f
2011-05-26 09:39:33.055 Switch[24344:40b] 009b
2011-05-26 09:39:33.055 Switch[24344:40b] 007b
2011-05-26 09:39:33.056 Switch[24344:40b] 0093
2011-05-26 09:39:33.056 Switch[24344:40b] 008d
2011-05-26 09:39:33.057 Switch[24344:40b] I want them to be together like 006700a1..

Comment: That's all the info `NSLog` appends. So you can safely ignore that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the elements of the array are strings containing comma separated hex numbers, the following produces another NSMutableArray with the anything but alphanumeric chars removed.

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:@"2f,40d,67f"];
for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) {
    NSString *element = [array objectAtIndex:i];
    NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:element.length];
    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:element];  
    NSCharacterSet *allowed = [NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet];  
    while ([scanner isAtEnd] == NO) {  
        NSString *buffer;  
        if ([scanner scanCharactersFromSet:allowed intoString:&buffer]) {  
            [result appendString:buffer]; 
        } else {        
            [scanner setScanLocation:([scanner scanLocation] + 1)];  
        }  
    }
    [array replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:result];
}
NSLog(@"array %@", array);
```

This prints `2f40d67f` but looks like a lot of work to do something so simple. :P

Comment: stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet will remove characters from start and end of string, not from the middle, so it seems your answer is wrong...

Comment: it does not work.I am using nslog to print the array.The array is taking some points my code is [myarray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%04x",(NSInteger)lastPoint.x ]];
    [myarray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%04x",(NSInteger)lastPoint.y ]];NSLog(@"%@",myarray);

Comment: any help plz.can someone help.

Comment: @Vladimir thanks, I wrote it another way, tried to at least, not sure what is asked here anymore :D